# Prove there is no covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Prove that there are no covering spaces $p: S^{1} \longrightarrow C$ whose base is a convex space and whose total space is $S^{1}$

Covering space def: Let $B$ be a space. A map $p:E\longrightarrow B$ is a covering space of $B$ if each point $b\in B$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}U$ is a disjoint union of open subsets $U_{\alpha} \subset E$ such that each $p\mid U_{\alpha}: U_{\alpha}\longrightarrow U$ is a homeomorphism.

I know that a subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is convex if for every $x,y \in C$ and any $t\in [0,1]$ we get $tx + (1-t)y \in C$, but I'm not sure where to start with this question and how to use this information

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is such a covering space, the induced map $p_* : \pi_1 (S^1) \to \pi_1 (C)$ is injective. Now $\pi_1 (S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_1 (C) = 0$, and there is no injective group homomoprhism $\mathbb{Z} \to 0$. This gives a contradiction.